# how do I request that my question be deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I recently asked a question that was subsequently put on hold.  I agree with the hold-reasons and think that this question should be deleted from the website.  As the original poster, how do I make such a request?

Comment: The system will delete it automatically in a week or so.

Answer (score 8):

There should be a delete link under your question.

[image: delete link for question]

If you do nothing (and the question does not have any up-votes, nor any answers with upvotes), the system will delete it automatically after 9 days.

From [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/307535):

> The system will automatically delete closed (not as a duplicate), unlocked questions with zero or negative score having no positively scored or accepted answers or pending reopen votes, that were closed 9 or more days ago and haven't been edited in the past 9 days.

Answer (score 2):

In cases when a question *must be deleted now*, maybe because it contains sensitive information that shouldn't have gone into the text in the first place, flag the question with "in need of moderator intervention" as the reason and explain what has happened.